Number of routes of Königsberg's Bridges problem in Cristopher Moore's "The Nature of Computation"
This is supposed to be a very simple question.
In the Prologue of Cristopher Moore's book "The Nature of Computation" (2011), page 3, the number of possible routes of the Königsberg problem is calculated as 2ⁿ with n=7.
Quote:

Assume for simplicity that each time we arrive on an island or a riverbank there are two different ways we could leave. Then if there are n bridges to cross, a rough estimate for the number of possible walks would be 2ⁿ.

I had a hard time making sense of this "rough estimate".
What is the possible mental model behind it?

It's actually Cristopher Moore, unusual spelling

He does not take the Euler problem but assumes that it is a graph in which each vertex has degree 3, so if you come in one edge (and do not want to exit back), you have 2 choices. E.g. in the exmple in your nswr, assume an extra bridge B-C

@kodlu Thanks! Corrected.

So I wrote a python code to actually enumerate all the possible unsuccessful "walks" a human would try (maybe with a pencil over the graph):
def get_remaining_paths(v, edges):
    paths = []
    for i,e in enumerate(edges):
        if v in e:
            edges_next = edges[:]
            edges_next.pop(i)
            if e[0] == v:
                vnext = e[1]
            else:
                vnext = e[0]
            paths_next = get_remaining_paths(vnext, edges_next)
            if len(paths_next) == 0:
                paths.append([(v, vnext)])
            else:
                for p in paths_next:
                    paths.append([(v, vnext)] + p)
    return paths
    
vertices = ['A', 'B', 'C', 'D']
edges = [('A','B'), ('A','B'), ('A','C'), ('A','C'), ('A','D'), ('B','D'), ('C','D')]
all_paths = {v: get_remaining_paths(v, edges) for v in vertices}
all_paths_nums = {v: len(all_paths[v]) for v in vertices}
success = {v: any([len(p)==len(edges) for p in all_paths[v]]) for v in vertices}    
print(all_paths_nums)
print(success)

The output is
{'A': 108, 'B': 90, 'C': 90, 'D': 84}
{'A': False, 'B': False, 'C': False, 'D': False}

which means the number of possible (unsuccessful) routes starting from 'A' is 108, from 'B' is 90, from 'C' is 90, and from 'D' is 84.
So the total number of trials is 372.  This is how many walks a person would try (ignoring Euler's reasoning and just performing a brute-force search).
Considering that 'B' and 'C' are symmetric, the total number can be reduced to 282.

